# how can to print custom progress bar with tqdm with concurrent?

Tags: python, threadpoolexecutor, tqdm

I have a program I want to show its progress, I'm trying to print a custom progress bar with tqdm library with concurrent thread pool
here is the code of what I'm trying

```
from  concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from tqdm import tqdm 
import time 

N = 30

def foo(a): #This is the function that i want it to be threaded 
    time.sleep(0.2)
    return a**2

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:  
    with tqdm(total=100, bar_format="{postfix[0]}{postfix[1][value]}{postfix[2]}{postfix[3]}",
          postfix=["Scanning word ", dict(value=0) ,' of ', N]) as t:
        list(t(executor.map(foo, range(N))))
```

but i get this error

TypeError: 'tqdm' object is not callable

Comment: i figured how to do it with bar_format and postfix

Comment: here is the code gist https://gist.github.com/Anas-jaf/8e922a9a09076a143140924146236ccb